# Return value from a method to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this javascript file structure:

```
class RandomCtrl {
    constructor(randomService) {
    this.randomService = randomService;
    ...
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);
    }

    ...

}

function getData(RandomCtrl) {
    ...
}


function getChart(data) {
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }

    const chartOptions = getWeekHourlyOptions(data);

    const allCols = [].concat(chartOptions.dataColumns);
    allCols.push(["x"].concat(_.map(chartOptions.xAxis, element => moment(element).valueOf())));
    const xVals = xAxisValues(chartOptions.xAxis);

    ...

}

...

RandomCtrl.$inject = ['randomService'];

export const Random = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<',
        siteNames: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: randomPageHtml,
    controller: RandomCtrl
};
```

I want to get the value of `allCols` to a variable. I tried to do it by adding `return allCols;` at the end of `getChart()` method and call it inside `$onInit()`.

Tried several ways like:

`const wow = getChart();`

`const wow = getChart(this);`

`const wow = getChart.call(null, this);`

All of them are saying that wow is **undefined**. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: why not declare `getChart` inside of your class?

Comment: Can you update your code snippet with where you are trying const wow = getChart();

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code where in addOneTimeListener wrapper will execute it when the table done being drawn and it should be after creating table but before calling draw.

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', function () {       
        var tmpData = table.getChart();
        // ...        
});
```